# How to control the workspace Jenkins starts the build on?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have one Jenkins controller node and 2 Jenkins agent nodes. All my job builds happen in the agent nodes. When I configured my agents, I set the `Remote root directory` as `/data/home/jenkins/jenkins-slave`. Also, I give the custom workspace option as `DEVELOP_BRANCH` in the job configuration page of the respective job.

However, at the start of job, I get the following log information:

```
Building remotely on linux in workspace /data/home/jenkins/jenkins-slave/workspace/DEVELOP_BRANCH
```

I want to start my builds in this location.

```
/data/home/jenkins/jenkins-slave/DEVELOP_BRANCH
```

Why does the extra workspace directory come into the picture? How do I remove it? I do not have access to Jenkins master node. So, if there is a workaround that can match my requirements, it would be awesome.

Note: By node, I refer to a Linux OS computer with redHat distribution.

Comment: This is a multijob project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In project configuration, under **Advanced Project Options**, you can check **Use custom workspace** and put a path there.

If you put an **absolute path**, it will be used without any extra *workspace/* directory. (at least that's the behavior I can see on a windows server.)